Creating a PowerShell Script to Backup a VHDX File
I have recently setup a virtual machine on a local computer which I need to backup to the onedrive folder on it each week. I put together the following PowerShell script to try and shut the vm down then use 7zip to do the compress and saving
    # Created 7-2-2024 for backing up VHDX files for company

#Variable Declarations
$SourcePath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Virtual Hard Disks\Accounting.vhdx"
$DestinationPath = "C:\Users\thisi\OneDrive - Default Directory\Documents"
$ZipDestinationPath = "C:\Users\thisi\OneDrive - Default Directory\Documents\Accounting $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip"

$BackupCount = 3
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationPath -filter "*.vhdx" | Sort-Object -property LastWriteTime -Descending

#Stop VM
Stop-VM -Name Accounting -TurnOff

$VM = Get-VM -Name Accounting

#if give vm time to shut down
while ($VM.State -ne "off")
{
start-sleep -s 5
}

#ensure vm is off before completing operation
if($VM.State -eq "off")
{

#compress file
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $7zipPath -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "7 zip executable '$7zipPath' not found"
}

Set-Alias Start-SevenZip $7zipPath

Start-SevenZip a -mx=9 $ZipDestinationPath $SourcePath


#start vm again
Start-VM -Name Accounting

if ($files.Count -gt $BackupCount) {
    # Select the files to delete
    $filesToDelete = $files | select -Skip $BackupCount

    #delete the selected files, confirm this is correct then remove the  
    $filesToDelete | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$false
}
}

Whenever it gets to the compressing and saving I draw the following issue:
7-Zip 24.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2024 Igor Pavlov : 2024-06-19

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 168423325696 bytes (157 GiB)

Creating archive: C:\Users\thisi\OneDrive - Default Directory\Documents\Accounting 2024-07-08.zip

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 168423325696 bytes (157 GiB)


Error:
cannot open file
C:\Users\thisi\OneDrive - Default Directory\Documents\Accounting 2024-07-08.zip
The system cannot find the file specified.


System ERROR:
The system cannot find the file specified.

I am very new to powershell scripting so any improvements you see as well as fixing this error would be helpful.
Thanks!!
